# Uploading image as Binary Data to cognitive Services with Node

Tags: node.js, image, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to pass the Microsoft Cognitive services facial API an image which the user has uploaded. The image is available on the server in the uploads folder.

Microsoft is expecting the image to be 'application/octet-stream' and passed as binary data.

I am currently unable to find a way to pass the image to the API that is satisfactory for it to be accepted and keep receiving "decoding error, image format unsupported". As far as im aware the image must be uploaded in blob or file format but being new to NodeJs im really unsure on how to achieve this.

So far i have this and have looked a few options but none have worked, the other options i tried returned simmilar errors such as 'file too small or large' but when ive manually tested the same image via Postman it works fine.

```
image.mv('./uploads/' + req.files.image.name , function(err) {
if (err)
  return res.status(500).send(err);
});

var encodedImage = new Buffer(req.files.image.data, 'binary').toString('hex');

let addAPersonFace = cognitive.addAPersonFace(personGroupId, personId, encodedImage);

addAPersonFace.then(function(data) {
  res.render('pages/persons/face', { data: data, personGroupId : req.params.persongroupid, personId : req.params.personid} );
})
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The package it looks like you're using, [cognitive-services](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cognitive-services), does not appear to support file uploads.  You might choose to raise an issue on the GitHub [page](https://github.com/joshbalfour/node-cognitive-services).

Alternative NPM packages do exist, though, if that's an option.  With [project-oxford](https://www.npmjs.com/package/project-oxford), you would do something like the following:

```
var oxford = require('project-oxford'),
    client = new oxford.Client(YOUR_FACE_API_KEY),
    uuid = require('uuid');

var personGroupId = uuid.v4();
var personGroupName = 'my-person-group-name';
var personName = 'my-person-name';
var facePath = './images/face.jpg';

// Skip the person-group creation if you already have one
console.log(JSON.stringify({personGroupId: personGroupId}));
client.face.personGroup.create(personGroupId, personGroupName, '')
  .then(function(createPersonGroupResponse) {
    // Skip the person creation if you already have one
    client.face.person.create(personGroupId, personName)
      .then(function(createPersonResponse) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(createPersonResponse))
        personId = createPersonResponse.personId;
        // Associate an image to the person
        client.face.person.addFace(personGroupId, personId, {path: facePath})
          .then(function (addFaceResponse) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(addFaceResponse));
          })
      })
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! Whilst it didn't answer my question directly, I ultimately decided that the package you suggested is a far more comprehensive and better supported and decided to use it in my project.

If I find an answer for the actual question I will post it here!

Comment: Didn't work for me, I get the error `Unhandled rejection Error: [object Object]
    at Object.ensureErrorObject (/Users/rodrigoruiz/Dropbox/Projetos/FaceRecognitionServer/NodeAPI/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:261:20)
    at Promise._rejectCallback (/Users/rodrigoruiz/Dropbox/Projetos/FaceRecognitionServer/NodeAPI/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:472:22)`. If I try running a similar code, i.e., with `readFileSync`, it also doesn't work, I get the error `StatusCodeError: 400 - {"error":{"code":"InvalidImage","message":"Decoding error, image format unsupported."}}`. Ideas why?

Comment: What happens if you feed that same image into the [demo](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/) page?

Answer (score 1):

Please update to version [0.2.0](https://github.com/joshbalfour/node-cognitive-services/tree/v0.2.0), this should work now.